# Unused pins of FMBA14

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, darlington

I am using NPN Darlington array [FMBA14](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/308/1/FMBA14_D-2313861.pdf). I am only using B1,C1 and E1 pins for my application. The other pins B2,C2 and E2 can be left floating?.

Can someone suggest anything on this?

Thank you

Comment: You may consider grounding them as well, if stray signals and interference are a concern.

Comment: Do whatever you like; leave it, parallel it , ground it or buffer a test pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet explicitly says that it's a multichip component so they are literally two separate darlingtons on two different dies. There's *nothing* joining them inside.

Just do whatever you want, you could even carefully cutting the package to get a spare transistor out probably